# Set package and theme at run time in magento2

Tags: magento2

My package name is 'company' and my theme name is 'web', and I have another package named 'system' whose theme is named 'component'.

Run time is from the Block file but I want to set that theme and package from the front-end side in magento2.

Comment: so, change your name to a more customized one

Answer (score 6):

If you want to Set package and theme at run time in magento simply use this code snippet.

1. create one function ex. changeTheme('Theme-name'); and run this function with your requirement
2. add this function in your head.phtml after php start.

   ```
    function changeTheme($themeName)
    {
      Mage::getDesign()->setArea('frontend') //Area (frontend|adminhtml)
                       ->setPackageName('default') //Name of Package
                       ->setTheme($themeName); // Name of theme
    }
   ```

enjoy :)

Answer (score 4):

You can set your theme programmatically by using the following code :

```php
Mage::getDesign()->setArea('frontend') //Area (frontend|adminhtml)
    ->setPackageName('default') //Name of Package
    ->setTheme('modern'); // Name of theme
```

http://roshanlal.in/magento/magento-programmatically-change-theme/#more-193

Comment: thanks for the help. but, this is applicable only for that particular action. what should i do if i want to set that theme for all page.

Answer (score 1):

You can write below code in action to set package and theme for the action:

```php
Mage::getDesign()->setArea(‘frontend’) //Area (frontend|adminhtml)
    ->setPackageName(‘default’) //Name of Package
    ->setTheme(‘modern’); // Name of theme
```

You may write the code in layout handler to set theme:

```xml
<reference name=”root”>
    <action method=”setTheme”>
        <theme>modern</theme>
    </action>
</reference>
```

Change page layout:

```xml
<reference name=”root”>
    <action method=”setTemplate”>
        <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
    </action>
</reference>
```

I hope it will surely help you.

Comment: Hi, the above code is for to set theme for that action. and whichever phtml file is associated for that action only that phtml file will be affected from that theme. i want to change theme for whole. is it possible ?

Comment: I have the same exact issue as Jen. The template files change, but the layout xml for the new theme does not get processed. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/17525/change-theme-dynamically-from-frontend-doesnt-update-xml-layout?noredirect=1#comment26170_17525