# Create block with template in Magento programmatically

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

I have in my Model class:

```
Mage::getDesign()->setArea(Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::AREA_FRONTEND);
$layout = Mage::app()->getLayout();
$block = $layout->createBlock('core/template','blockname');
$block->setTemplate('cronjob/items.phtml');
$blockProducts = $block->toHtml();
```

If I use these, Magento warns me with the message:

CRIT (2): Not valid template file: frontend\base\default\template\cronjob/items.phtml

File items.phtml is at these path:
C:\wamp\www\magento\app\design\frontend\default\customtheme\template\cronjob\items.phtml

Comment: The error message and your file location specify different packages/themes.  Have you tried setting the theme programmatically?  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17649587/set-package-and-theme-at-run-time-in-magento

Comment: Tnx for answer, but I already have defined theme and package in back office of Magento

Answer (score 0):

copy your items.phtml file from

```
C:\wamp\www\magento\app\design\frontend\default\customtheme\template\cronjob\items.phtml
```

to

```
C:\wamp\www\magento\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\cronjob/items.phtml
```

Comment: No, I don't want these solution. File must be at customtheme